# node.js server.listen on a specific IP address EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js

When I try to listen on a specific IP address, I am getting an error.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, "10.211.56.1");

console.log('Server running at http://10.211.56.1:8080/');
```

I get the following error:

```
➜  node-test  sudo node server.js
Server running at http://10.211.56.1:8080/
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1139:19)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
    at net.js:1280:9
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically means the ip/port combo you are using is not available to your server. This could be because the port is already in use, or, that ip address isn't one your server is using.

You should instead be either using `localhost:someport` or `0.0.0.0:someport`, where `someport` is a port that isn't currently being used.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make an ip address become available? What I am trying to do is set up an entry in my hosts file so I can have a url for an app and localhost is not an option.

Comment: That ip address would have to be given to you by your network. In either case,  you should use `0.0.0.0` in most situations unless your server has multiple ip addresses.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is I am trying to run 2 apps locally for testing. app1.test.dev and app2.test.dev. Additionally, I have some apps running on localhost on specific ports. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: Not really. Usually when running multiple apps, the only real option is to use multiple ports. If you want multiple apps running on port 80, you can put a webserver capable of doing a reverse-proxy (such as iis nginx or apache) that will proxy a `domain.com:80` to your `localhost:7352`, thus allowing you to run many applications using the same ip address and port 80 outward facing. You'll of course still need to route that domain to your server in your network.

Comment: Ok. got it. I will set up a reverse proxy. Thanks.

Comment: What if I actually want to spoof an IP address? I need to do that to force a game to connect to specific IP.

Comment: @TomášZato what does that have to do with this answer? usually you reach for a VPN for that job.