# Node.js seems to ignore my IP address i give, instead it uses localhost to open the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I tried to solve it by myself, but i failed. At first i was just trying to create the simplest localhost server i could, and it worked, so i thought about online server (by port forwarding), for my friends to check my code out. I guess there is something i did competely wrong, so i'm asking you. The code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    hostname: '178.217.195.9',
    port: 45555
};

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end("working?");
});

server.listen(options, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at 178.217.195.9:45555`);
});`
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/docs/v8.11.2/api/synopsis.html

I was trying to run this code on the latest version (10.3.0), and today i tried with recommended one (8.11.2). No changes, so i guess it has to be my fault.

What's happening? When i check (after port forwarding) the 178.217.195.9:45555, it doesn't exist.

But when i check localhost:45555, it works. I don't know what to say about it.

It's weird, as the topic says, it seems to ignore my IP i typed, changing it with localhost.

Maybe the code is wrong. I've heard "just change 127.0.0.1 with your public IP and should work", so i did it.

Is this code **only** for localhost servers?

I don't know if it will help in any way, but normally i'm using p5.js library (The Coding Train), port forwarding is set as: **Service Port** - 45555, **IP Address** - 192.168.0.103 (checked in cmd), **Internal Port** - 45555, **Protocol** - TCP or UDP.

I added exception to my firewall for 45555 port. Sometimes, when i try to change my code, to test other options, but the concept is the same, it says **Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 178.217.195.9:45555**.

Changing the port doesnt help. Then im usually back to ^ this code. Through control panel i made my IP static. Ip adress: 192.168.0.103, Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1, Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 (if it will help in any way).

Previously (i don't remember when exactly but more than 3 months ago) i also set prefered DNS servers as: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. Current Node.js version is 8.11.2, npm 6.1.0. I don't really want to use Heroku or other programs like that. I've heard something about WebSockets, was messing a little around it but nothing really happened. I don't any other ideas about useful informations there. I hope somebody will help me, i'll answer every question about other informations.

Comment: You can use network assigned ip only from your connected network, you cannot assign your own ip to your host

Answer (score 1):

In the options has to be `host` and not `hostname`. So for your code `host` is not present in the options and as of that `localhost` is used as default.

[server.listen(options[, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_options_callback)

> ```
> server.listen(options[, callback])
> # Added in: v0.11.14
>
> options <Object> Required. Supports the following properties:
>     port <number>
>     host <string>
>     path <string> Will be ignored if port is specified. See Identifying paths for IPC connections.
>     backlog <number> Common parameter of server.listen() functions.
>     exclusive <boolean> Default: false
>     readableAll <boolean> For IPC servers makes the pipe readable for all users. Default: false
>     writableAll <boolean> For IPC servers makes the pipe writable for all users. Default: false
> callback <Function> Common parameter of server.listen() functions.
> Returns: <net.Server>
> ```

Comment: @SuperHero https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_options_callback is not a dark place but the official documentation of node. So that's the first place to check the API.

Comment: @SuperHero about the `EADDRNOTAVAIL` that's a different question.  [node.js server.listen on a specific IP address EADDRNOTAVAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634008). Probably the PC node runs on doe snot have that IP (probably behind a router with only a local ip) or the port is used.